In org-agenda, how can I jump to tomorrow?
There's a shortcut, ".", in org-agenda that lets me jump to today.
Is there such a shortcut that takes me to tomorrow or somehow jump forward by day?;)

Do C-h m in the agenda and check out what's available. Seems like you are looking for C-c C-n, bound to org-agenda-next-date-line.

If I put point on Tuesday and then M-x org-agenda-next-date-line, it does not jump to Wednesday.

Try with emacs -Q and if it works there, you know the drill.

This function does a simple regexp search for a line that does not start with whitespace. What does you agenda look like? Pleast post an example in your question.

This indeed works;). I don't know why I experienced that it didn't work, but it does indeed work now;). Thanks.
